# How to know my distribution build is correct or not?

Tags: iphone, distribution

I have created distribution certificate and Provisioning profile  for app store submission .
I have created build also. but how can I know that my build is correct ?
Here is my build log

> Build Csharp Tutorial of project Csharp Tutorial with configuration
>   Distribution
>
> CodeSign "build/Distribution-iphoneos/Csharp Tutorial.app" cd
>   "/Users/gurpreetsinghchawla/Documents/Csharp Tutorial " setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>   /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Classified Solutions
>   Group, Inc."
>   "--resource-rules=/Users/gurpreetsinghchawla/Documents/Csharp Tutorial
>   /build/Distribution-iphoneos/Csharp Tutorial.app/ResourceRules.plist"
>   --entitlements "/Users/gurpreetsinghchawla/Documents/Csharp Tutorial
>   /build/Csharp Tutorial.build/Distribution-iphoneos/Csharp
>   Tutorial.build/Csharp Tutorial.xcent"
>   "/Users/gurpreetsinghchawla/Documents/Csharp Tutorial
>   /build/Distribution-iphoneos/Csharp Tutorial.app"
>
> /Users/gurpreetsinghchawla/Documents/Csharp Tutorial
>   /build/Distribution-iphoneos/Csharp Tutorial.app: replacing existing
>   signature
>
> Validate "build/Distribution-iphoneos/Csharp Tutorial.app" cd
>   "/Users/gurpreetsinghchawla/Documents/Csharp Tutorial " setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
>   "/Users/gurpreetsinghchawla/Documents/Csharp Tutorial
>   /build/Distribution-iphoneos/Csharp Tutorial.app"
>
> 2011-08-30 10:43:17.313 Validation[286:607] *** Warning: Defaulting to
>   the standard codesign tool

Why it is showing warning??